# Problem with margins

Tags: margins, double-sided

I need to set margins. The odd pages should have left margin 3.5 cm and right margin 2.5 cm. The even pages should have left margin 2.5 cm and right margin 3.5 cm. I tried to do it but for example by option `\oddsidemargin` the left margin on odd page moves to the right but the right margin shrinks.

The `.cls` file is [HERE](http://exdb.fit.cvut.cz/browser/zp/1213-zima/martiada/FITthesis.cls?rev=1217).

Document:

```
\documentclass[thesis=B,czech]{FITthesis}[2012/06/26]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\department{text}
\title{text}
\authorGN{text}
\authorFN{text}
\authorWithDegrees{text}
\supervisor{text}
\acknowledgements{text}
\abstractCS{text}
\abstractEN{text}
\placeForDeclarationOfAuthenticity{text}
\declarationOfAuthenticityOption{1}
\keywordsCS{text}
\keywordsEN{text}

\begin{document}

\begin{introduction}
    %
\end{introduction}

\chapter First


\begin{conclusion}
    %
\end{conclusion}

\appendix

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer myself.

To add...

```
\usepackage[inner=3.5cm,outer=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

...is solution.